# Reading Large Number from Excel file using oledb Error

Tags: oledb

Hello i am facing a problem.
I am fetching a large excel file Using oledb.
Everything is working fine but in some fields there are Large number(12 digit) like- 499170824654 but it's returning then 4.99171E+11

Answer (score 0):

Convert the Largenumber.

```
Int64 largeInt = Convert.ToInt64(LargeNumber);
```